# What is the best conversion from String into UnsafePointer<Int8>?

Tags: swift, foundation

To convert `String` into UnsafePointer I use this:

`var tail = ("" as NSString).utf8String`

But is there any way to convert without `NSString` casting?

I use `UnsafePointer` inside `C-library` methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's special method exactly for this: [.withCString(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1538904-withcstring):

```
yourString.withCString { pointer in
    // work with the pointer
    return result
}
```

Or if you want it as property there's [.utf8CString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2430818-utf8cstring):

```
var tail = "".utf8CString // ContiguousArray<CChar> (aka ContiguousArray<Int8>)
// and then
tail.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in
    // work with the pointer
    return result
}
```

Comment: By the way , this is immutable solution

Comment: @Vyacheslav, there were no mutability requirement in the question. But you can turn `UnsafePointer` into `UnsafeMutablePointer` using this [`init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer/2431122-init). But you won't be able to change content of original `String` though, I guess when you ask for `C string` new contiguous area of memory gets reserved and filled with data from original string, and may only change what's in that new area.